# Inorder to have a search feature on data in database which one has better performance: elasticsearch or sphinx?

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, sphinx

We have a database which stores 10 millions of records every day. I wanna have a filter query on data within specific date range but it's very slow on SQL Server, then I decided to move data to one of the Full-Text Search engine such as elasticsearch or sphinx to have  faster search but I wander which one has  greater performance in search.

I have used elasticsearch before and familiar with it's features but do not have any experience with sphinx.

thnx

Comment: [Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017)